# Entity Framework June 2011 CTP and SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, entity-framework, ctp

I have a spatial model definition which used to be working with SQL Server 2008 but not with 2012 anymore.

I don't know why but I can't get it working...

```
model.Location = DbGeography.Parse("POINT(" + model.Latitude + " " + model.Longitude + ")");
```

I am getting this exception:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146232828
>   Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   Source=mscorlib
>   StackTrace:
>   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, 
>   CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlSpatialServices.GeographyFromText(String
>   geographyText)
>   at System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography.Parse(String geographyText)
>   at b.Helpers.Repository.saveFoursquareMarkers(List`1 fs) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\b\Helpers\Repository.cs:line 182
>
>   at b.Controllers.KayController.GetMarkers(String lat, String lng, String type, Double dist, String today, String google) in
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\b\Controllers\KayController.cs:line 29
>
>   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>
>   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters)
>
>   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)
>
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass42.b*_41()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c_*DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult
>   _)
>
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Object tag)
>
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c*_DisplayClass37.<>c_*DisplayClass39.b*_33()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass4f.b*_49()
>
> InnerException: System.FormatException
>   HResult=-2146233033
>   Message=24141: A number is expected at position 21 of the input. The input has ,905651030368.
>   Source=Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
>   StackTrace:
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisWktReader.RecognizeDouble()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisWktReader.ParsePointText(Boolean
>   parseParentheses)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisWktReader.ParseTaggedText(OpenGisType
>   type)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisWktReader.Read(OpenGisType type,
>   Int32 srid)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType
>   type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.STGeomFromText(SqlChars
>   geometryTaggedText, Int32 srid)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.Parse(SqlString s)

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was really not understandable with this error but the problem was the localization of my computer.

It was expecting a dot (.) rather than coma (,) as my decimal symbol. I've just set it from Start>Control Panel>Region and Language>Additional Settings and voila. It is working now.

Thank you for your helps.

Comment: I also removed my GIS software with SQL 2008. Usually this GIS software was changing the dot with coma automatically but this time it was not possible for me to realize that. Sorry, if I made trouble for you also.

Answer (score 0):

Unistall the CTP and install .NET Framework 4.5 beta. If you still have the problem update the thread.